# multiplication in matrix R

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

Look, what I want to do: [In Excel is clear and easy, but in R I have a problem...:(]

```
Column A 1 2 3 4 5
Column B 0 9 2 1 7
```

That's my real "algorithm":

```
Column C 
(first value) = mean(Column A) = 3
(second value) = ((mean(Column A)*4) + 0)/5 =  2,4
(third value) = ((second value*4) + 9)/5 = 3,72
etc.
```

So we have:

```
#   A B  C
# 1 1 0  3
# 2 2 9 2,4
# 3 3 2 3,72
# 4 4 1 3,37
# 5 5 7 2,90
```

This is my actually code with your suggestion:

```
a <- c(1:5)
b <- c(0,9,0,1,7,0)

matrix <- data.frame(A=a,B=b)
matrix <- c(mean(matrix$A), (cumsum(matrix$B) + (mean(matrix$A)*4))/5)
```

This is solution: 2.4 4.2 4.2 4.4 5.8 (WRONG !!)

Of course R write me error that: "replacement has 6 rows, data has 5" but this isn't relevant...I only want to know, how should I do it??

Comment: -1: see [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to SO.  As Blazej pointed out, it is good practice to explain what you have tried and where you are stuck.  This way we can help you learn, rather than just giving a magic incantation that solves your problem.

Comment: I can't resist suggesting that any statement containing both the words "Excel" and "clear" should be auto-downvoted by 10.   But that aside, your algorithm for "column C" is unclear.  In addition, since the values in `C` have no relationship to the `A` and `B` values in the same rows, I recommend against assembling the data in that sort of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `?cumsum`:

```
a <- 1:5
b <- c(0, 9, 2, 1, 7)

mean(a) + cumsum(b)
# [1]  3 12 14 15 22
```

**UPDATE:**

It seems you want to run a (weighted) moving average. Maybe you should have a look at the [TTR package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TTR/index.html).

Please find an easy approach below:

```
wma <- function(b, startValue, a=4/5) {
  m <- double(length(b)+1)
  m[1] <- startValue
  for (i in seq(along=b)) {
    m[i+1] <- a * m[i] + (1-a) * b[i]
  }
  return(m)
}

wma(b, mean(a))
# [1] 3.00000 2.40000 3.72000 3.37600 2.90080 3.72064
```

Comment: Sgibb you didn't understand my problem....look again what I want to do, please :)

Comment: @Blazej: Your first problem was completely different. I couldn't understand your real problem first because you didn't describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This solves your issue:

```
mydf<-data.frame(A=1:5, B=c(0,9,2,1,7))
mydf$C<-cumsum(mydf$B)+mean(mydf$A)

mydf 
#   A B  C
# 1 1 0  3
# 2 2 9 12
# 3 3 2 14
# 4 4 1 15
# 5 5 7 22
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry Mike, no +1 from me because this is nominally exactly the same as the prior answer @sgibb gives below

Comment: Ha ha, yeah I guess I took too long to write the code. I should have refreshed my browswer before posting. :)